# Zephyr hello world application failed for ESP32

Tags: build, cross-platform, esp32, zephyr-rtos

OS: Ubuntu 18.04,64bit (New Installed) 
Zephyr Version: 2.2.99 
Zephyr SDK Version: 0.11.2 
xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc Version: 5.2.0 --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu

As per getting started guide for Zephyr and esp, we have set environment variable.

> export ZEPHYR_TOOLCHAIN_VARIANT="espressif"
>   export ESPRESSIF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH="/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/esp/xtensa-esp32-elf" 
>   export ZEPHYR_SDK_INSTALL_DIR="/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zephyr-sdk"

We building hello_world application:

> west build -b esp32 samples/hello_world

[84/122] Building ASM object modules/xtensa/CMakeFiles/modules_xtensa_hal.dir/src/hal/cache_asm.S.obj 
FAILED: modules/xtensa/CMakeFiles/modules_xtensa_hal.dir/src/hal/cache_asm.S.obj  
ccache /home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/esp/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc -DBUILD_VERSION=zephyr-v2.2.0-844-g6c2451c5c0a6 -DKERNEL -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D__ZEPHYR__=1 -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/include -Izephyr/include/generated -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/soc/xtensa/esp32 -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/soc/xtensa/esp32/include -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/esp-idf/zephyr/../components/esp32/include -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/esp-idf/zephyr/../components/soc/esp32/include -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/xtensa/include -I/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/xtensa/zephyr/soc/esp32 -isystem /home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/lib/libc/minimal/include -isystem /home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/esp/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/include -isystem /home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/esp/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/5.2.0/include-fixed -Os -imacros/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/build/zephyr/include/generated/autoconf.h -ffreestanding -fno-common -g -xassembler-with-cpp -imacros/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/zephyr/include/toolchain/zephyr_stdint.h -D_ASMLANGUAGE -Wall -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-main -Wno-pointer-sign -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Werror=implicit-int -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-pie -fno-pic -fno-strict-overflow -fno-reorder-functions -fno-defer-pop -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mlongcalls -nostdinc -MD -MT modules/xtensa/CMakeFiles/modules_xtensa_hal.dir/src/hal/cache_asm.S.obj -MF modules/xtensa/CMakeFiles/modules_xtensa_hal.dir/src/hal/cache_asm.S.obj.d -o modules/xtensa/CMakeFiles/modules_xtensa_hal.dir/src/hal/cache_asm.S.obj -c /home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/xtensa/src/hal/cache_asm.S 
/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/xtensa/src/hal/cache_asm.S: Assembler messages: 
/home/swapna/Documents/Workspace/Zephyr_ESP/zp/modules/hal/xtensa/src/hal/cache_asm.S:186: Error: unknown opcode or format name 'declfunc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in environment path. 
 
1. ESPRESSIF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH

Build the esp32's hello world application using [esp_guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/index.html#get-started-setup-toochain). 
As per the documentation about how to build the toolchain path is set in

> $HOME/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r1-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/

Changed this setting and tried building again. Again build failed [error](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/issues/24227)

2. Build still getting failed. I checked the issues related to esp32 on the github. Came across with [this](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/pull/24266). 
   So, I modified in the code as per the changes mentioned in the commit. 
   And Voila!! It worked. Successfully build and flashed on esp32.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated version of the environment setup:
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/xtensa/esp32/doc/index.html

You can now use `west espressif install` and `west espressif update` to manage toolchain. Still, you need to provide path to toolchain binaries in environmental variables, i.e add this to your `~/.profile`:

```
export ESPRESSIF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH="${HOME}/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf"
export PATH=$PATH:$ESPRESSIF_TOOLCHAIN_PATH/bin
```